# I want to open a pop-up window that will depend on what the user inputs on several prompts alerts using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, window, document, with-statement

I have direction on opening and closing the data stream and assign the values backColor and textColor to the variables bicolor and fgcolor as well as using the write() method to output pageContent. I want to do write all of these statements inside a "with" statement. This is the code I currently have which is opening a new window but not displaying any content.
I am doing this to learn how to use JavaScript rather than to create a webpage, however I am aware that the with statement is not recommended but this does not matter in this moment.

```
<script>
function writeToDocument(){
var textColor, backColor, pageTitle;
var yourText, pageContent, docWindow;

textColor = prompt("Please enter a text color:","white");
backColor = prompt("Please enter a background color:","black");
pageTitle = prompt("The page will be titled: ","Default Title");
yourText = prompt("Add content to the new document:", "page content");

pageContent = "<html><head><title>";
pageContent += pageTitle + "</title>";
pageContent += "<script>alert('The page ' + document.title + ' was created: ' + document.lastModified)</script>";
pageContent += "</head><body><strong>";
pageContent += "</strong></body></html>";

docWindow = open("","docWin","width=250,height=150,resizable=1,status=1");
// Write your code here
with (docWindow.document){
docWindow.document.open();
bgcolor= backColor;
fgcolor = textColor;
docWindow.document.write(pageContent);
docWindow.document.close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a `with` statement? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modified code of yours:

```
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", writeToDocument);

        function writeToDocument() {
            //alert("DOMContent is ready.");
            //declaration of variables
            var textColor, backColor, pageTitle;
            var yourText, pageContent, docWindow;
           //prompt user to input values
            textColor = prompt("Please enter a text color:", "white");
            backColor = prompt("Please enter a background color:", "black");
            pageTitle = prompt("The page will be titled: ", "Default Title");
            yourText = prompt("Add content to the new document:", "page content");
            
            pageContent = "<html><head><title>";
            pageContent += pageTitle;
            pageContent += "</title>";
            pageContent += "<script>";
            pageContent += "alert('The page ' + document.title + ' was created: ' + document.lastModified)";
            pageContent += "<" + "/script>";
            pageContent += "</head><body><strong>" + yourText + "</strong></body></html>";

            docWindow = open("", "docWin", "width=250,height=150,resizable=1,status=1");

            // Write your code here
            with(docWindow.document) {
                docWindow.document.open();
                docWindow.document.backColor = 'backColor';
                docWindow.document.textColor = 'textColor';
                docWindow.document.write(pageContent);
                docWindow.document.close();
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>


</body>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.